# Are $\dfrac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}$ and $\sqrt {|a_n|}$ divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose $a_n$ is a convergent sequence. Which of the following may diverge?

$$\dfrac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}$$
$$\sqrt {|a_n|}$$
$$\sqrt[2n+1]{|a_n|}$$

I think that the last two should share the same answer because it's just a matter of how one counts members of a sequence.

Answer (score 4):

The first can diverge, take for example the sequence
$$ a_n = \frac{-1^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}}{n}.$$
It has subsequences that converge to $\pm 1$ respectively.

For the other two, noting that $x \mapsto \sqrt{|x|}$ is a continuous function, you might be able to figure out the answer.

**Edit:** corrected the sequence $a_n$, since $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ did converge, as pointed out by GitGud.

Comment: Thank you for the first example. I've no idea what to do with continuity, unfortunately.

Comment: If f is continous, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x_n) = f(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n)$

Comment: So, the last two are convergent. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The third sequence does not have to converge.

Consider, for example 
$$
a_n = \begin{cases} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2n+1}, &\text{if $n$ is even}\\
\left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^{2n+1}, &\text{if $n$ is odd} \end{cases}
$$

Then $a_n \to 0$, but $\sqrt[2n+1]{|a_n|}$ alternates between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first counter example :

for non-zero $n$ :

- $a_{2n}= \dfrac{1}{n}$
- $a_{2n-1}= \dfrac{1}{n^2}$

$a_n$ converges to $0$.

but $\dfrac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n-1}}= n$, and therefore $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ diverges

Comment: @epsilo Take a look at my comment in the other answer and look at this answer.